# Powershell parsing problem with kubectl --field-selector

Tags: powershell, parsing, kubectl

Why does this Powershell command sequence using 2 field selectors and Powershell variable $Node not return any pods?

```
$Node = "mynode000001"
$pods = (kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node -A -o json | ConvertFrom-Json).items
```

But - this Powershell command sequence does return pods

```
$Node = "mynode000001"
$command = "kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node -A -o json"
$pods = (Invoke-Expression $command | ConvertFrom-Json).items
```

Is there a more elegant fix than pre-parsing the command then calling it an invoke-expression?

Breaking the problem down into smaller chunks, I suspect the comma separating the field selectors is breaking the parsing of the Powershell variable after the comma, but don't know a more elegant solution than pre-parsing the command.

This Powershell command sequence with a single field selector and Powershell variable $Node returns K8s pods:

```
$Node = "mynode000001"
$pods = (kubectl get pods --field-selector spec.nodeName=$Node -A -o json | ConvertFrom-Json).items
```

This Powershell command with 2 kubectl field selectors separated by a comma and hard coded node name returns pods:

```
$pods = (kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=mynode000001 -A -o json | ConvertFrom-Json).items
```

Comment: Try quoting the fieldselector - ```--field-selector "status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node"```. Not sure if ```kubectl``` will actually like that, but PowerShell will interpret it as a string instead of an array of values. If you compare the parsed commands you can see the difference in how it interprets it as a ```DoubleQuoted``` string instead of a ```System.Object[]``` - ```{ kubectl get pods --field-selector "status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node" -A -o json }.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements | fl```

Comment: It looks fine in echoargs, unless the nodeName needs literal quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

Wrap the `--field-selector` argument value in double quotes and it should work - i.e.

```
$pods = (kubectl get pods --field-selector "status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node" -A -o json | ConvertFrom-Json).items
#                                          ^                                           ^
```

### Long Version

So from doing a bit of testing, it looks like your assessment is correct - the comma in `--field-selector status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node` *is* the issue, or at least it's *partly* the issue...

What's happening is PowerShell is parsing the argument value as an **array**, which is fine, *but* it's not then performing variable expansion, which is surprising (to me at least).

The actual command being invoked is literally:

```
$Node = "mynode000001";
kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node -A -o json
```

as if you'd typed exactly that into a command prompt yourself - e.g.

```
C:\> kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node -A -o json
#                                                                            ^^^^^ :-(
```

If you quote the argument value it behaves differently:

```
$Node = "mynode000001";
kubectl get pods --field-selector "status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node" -A -o json
```

is the same as:

```
C:\> kubectl get pods --field-selector "status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=mynode000001" -A -o json
#                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ :-)
```

You can see the difference if you examine the AST generated by the parser:

```
{ kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node -A -o json }.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements

... snip ...

# System.Object[]
Elements   : {status.phase!=Succeeded, spec.nodeName=$Node}
StaticType : System.Object[]
Extent     : status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node
Parent     : kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node -A -o json

... snip ...
```

versus

```
{ kubectl get pods --field-selector "status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node" -A -o json }.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements[4] | fl *

... snip ...

# DoubleQuoted
Value              : status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node
StringConstantType : DoubleQuoted
NestedExpressions  : {$Node}
StaticType         : System.String
Extent             : "status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node"
Parent             : kubectl get pods --field-selector "status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node" -A -o json

... snip ...
```

The `DoubleQuoted` string has variable expansion applied, but the elements in the `System.Object[]` do not, it seems.

Digging further, it looks like the `$Node` expression is being identified in the unquoted argument value, but it's being parsed into a `BareWord` which doesn't get expanded...

```
 { kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node -A -o json }.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements[4].Elements[1] | fl *

# BareWord
Value              : spec.nodeName=$Node
StringConstantType : BareWord
NestedExpressions  : {$Node}
StaticType         : System.String
Extent             : spec.nodeName=$Node
Parent             : status.phase!=Succeeded,spec.nodeName=$Node
```

I don't know if that's by design or a bug, tbh, (probably the former at a guess) but quoting the argument value bypasses that whole question :-).